# Create extension method with `SyntaxGenerator`

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I'm trying to generate an extension method like that:

```
public static T MethodName<T>(this TypeName paramName)
{
    //extra stuff
    throw new ArgumentException();
}
```

I've achieved that with `SyntaxFactory`, but the code is huge and bulky.

```
var method = SyntaxFactory.MethodDeclaration(
                SyntaxFactory.List<AttributeListSyntax>(),
                SyntaxFactory.TokenList(
                    SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword),
                    SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.StaticKeyword)
                    ),
                SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName("T"),
                null,
                SyntaxFactory.Identifier("MethodName"),
                SyntaxFactory.TypeParameterList(
                    SyntaxFactory.SeparatedList(
                        new[] {
                            SyntaxFactory.TypeParameter(SyntaxFactory.Identifier("T"))
                        }
                    )
                ),
                SyntaxFactory.ParameterList(
                    SyntaxFactory.SeparatedList(new[]
                    {
                        SyntaxFactory.Parameter(SyntaxFactory.List<AttributeListSyntax>(),
                            SyntaxFactory.TokenList(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.ThisKeyword)),
                            SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName("TypeName"), SyntaxFactory.Identifier("paramName"), null)
                    })
                ),
                SyntaxFactory.List<TypeParameterConstraintClauseSyntax>(),
                SyntaxFactory.Block(),
                null
            );

method = method.AddBodyStatements(
    SyntaxFactory.ThrowStatement(
        SyntaxFactory.ObjectCreationExpression(
            SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName("ArgumentException"),
            SyntaxFactory.ArgumentList(),
            null
        )
    )
);
```

I was trying to do just the same thing but with `SyntaxGenerator` and came up to this:

```
var parameter =
    generator.ParameterDeclaration("paramName", SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName("TypeName"));

var methodDeclaration = generator.MethodDeclaration(
    "As",
    new[] { parameter },
    new[] { "T" },
    accessibility: Accessibility.Public,
    modifiers: DeclarationModifiers.Static,
    returnType: SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName("T")
);
```

This code generates the following code:

```
public static T As<T>(global::TypeName paramName)
{
}
```

How to add `this` modifier to parameter? `SyntaxGenerator.WithModifiers` takes `DeclarationModifier` not `SyntaxNode` so I'm not able to pass `SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.ThisKeyword)`.

Answer (score 1):

To add `this` modifier to the parameter you need to cast returned from `generator.ParameterDeclaration` to `ParameterSyntax`, and you'll be able to add modifier through the `WithModifiers` method.

```
var parameter =
    generator.ParameterDeclaration("paramName", SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName("TypeName"));

if (parameter is ParameterSyntax paramSyntax)
{
    parameter = paramSyntax.WithModifiers(
        SyntaxFactory.TokenList(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.ThisKeyword)));
}

var methodDeclaration = generator.MethodDeclaration(
    "As",
    new[] { parameter },
    new[] { "T" },
    accessibility: Accessibility.Public,
    modifiers: DeclarationModifiers.Static,
    returnType: SyntaxFactory.ParseTypeName("T")
);
```